# Finding wave vector using Data

Tags: wavefunction, astrophysics, data-analysis

I have 50 data for each velocity components ux, uy in vector form in two columns. so $\mathbf{U} = u_x\hat{x}+u_y\hat{y}$.

Moreover, $\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U_0} + \delta \mathbf{u}$ where the equilibrium part $\mathbf{U_0} = mean(ux)+mean(uy)$ () and $\delta \mathbf{u}$ is the perturbed part. The perturbed part $\delta u = \delta u'exp(\omega*t - \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x})$ with $\delta u'$, $\omega$, $k$ are the amplitude, frequency and wave vector.

I found the fluctuations in velocity components $u_{mx}(i) = U_x(i) - mean(U_x)$ (fluctuation in $u_x$) and $u_{my}(i) = U_x(i) - mean(U_x)$ (fluctuation in $u_y$).

how can I find $k_{mx}$, $k_{my}$ as well as $k_m$ ?

Hints: I need to solve a matrix for velocity components, and minimum eigen value of that will show the direction of minimum variance and I can find the value of $k_m$ (though I am not clear)

I appreciate any suggestion to find the fluctuation in wave vector ($k_{mx}$, $k_{my}$) using Data. Thanks in advance.